# pgpass not executing when creating backup

Tags: backup, passwords, putty

I have a backup1.sh file in home/my_dictonary/backup1.sh which creates a backup of my database

```
#!/bin/sh

tar -czf /home/ruud/backup1.tgz /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp

pg_dump -U dbadmin  -h 127.0.0.1 my_databasename -f /home/ruud/dbbackup.sql
```

I want to create a system that automatically creates a backup every day. So I created a .pgpass file in the same dictonary

```
149.210.204.94:5432:my_databasename:my_username:my_password
```

but when I run the code in putty it still asks for a password

```
root@149-210-204-94:~# /home/my_dictonary/backup1.sh
```

Whats the reason it doesnt run .pgpass?